# Access field value in a function in Power Query M

Tags: powerquery, m

I want to create a function that gets the first value of a table field if two other field values match the two given function parameters.

I thought this would be easy. But I found nothing in the internet or M documentation that could solve this.

I don't know if I have to loop through a record or if there is a top level function.

```
= (val1 as text, val2 as text) as text =>
let
    result = if [Field1] = val1 and [Field2] = val2 then [Field3] else ""
in
    result
```

Comment: a function does not have access to the field outside of it, you will have to pass the fields as parameters aswell

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your wish, table and column names are hard coded (i.e. you intend to apply the function only for specific table). Then you may use following approach:

```
// table
let
    t1 = #table({"Field1"}, List.Zip({{"a".."e"}})),
    t2 = #table({"Field2"}, List.Zip({{"α".."ε"}})),
    join = Table.Join(t1&t1,{}, t2&t2,{}),
    add = Table.AddIndexColumn(join, "Field3", 0, 1)
in
    add

// func
(val1 as text, val2 as text) => Table.SelectRows(table, each [Field1] = val1 and [Field2] = val2)[Field3]{0}

// result
func("d","β") //31
```